# Difference between 怒鳴る and 怒鳴りつける

Tags: word-choice, words, verbs, word-usage, compound-verbs

Jisho says 怒鳴る is an intransitive verb and that 怒鳴りつける is transitive. But I have come across the following phrases:

1. 止めようとしても母親は自分を怒鳴りつけるだけでした。
2. 彼女は私を怒鳴った。

If Jisho is really right, why "私を怒鳴った”　and not "私に怒鳴った”？

Answer (score 2):

These verbs are both intransitive and transitive. You can say all of ～を怒鳴る, ～を怒鳴りつける, ～に怒鳴る and ～に怒鳴りつける. These are all very common and I don't think there is a large difference between ～を and ～に. You can check this using [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/).